# Is it grammatically correct to say "I have just wanted to say that..."?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to say the following?

> I have just wanted to say that...

Considering that just=only and I have been waiting for my turn for some time before saying it.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "I have just wanted to say that..." may be commonly used in casual conversation, **it is not grammatically correct**.

The phrase *"have wanted"* is in the 'present perfect' tense, which implies an action that started in the past and is still continuing in the present. However, the word *"just"* implies that the action was completed very recently, in the present or very close to the present.

To correct the sentence, you can use the 'simple past' tense, such as " I just wanted to say that .. " or the present perfect continuous tense, " I have been wanting to say that ... "

Comment: This is wrong. It is perfectly grammatical. I have just wanted to say for a long time. Just=only.

Comment: Yes, "I have only wanted to say that..." is grammatically correct, but "I have just wanted to say that..." is not.

Comment: Something like "I have just been to France" or "I have just thought about buying a bicycle" is grammatical, but "I have just wanted" sounds a bit odd.

Comment: OP (Anastasia) indicates the just = only (= merely) sense, not the temporal sense, Sahil.

Comment: @StuartF I have just wanted to say to you that I disagree completely but am only saying it now.